# How to prove $\frac{1}{a_1^2}+\frac{1}{2a_2^2}+\frac{1}{3a_3^2}+...+\frac{1}{na_n^2}<2.$

Tags: inequality

> If $n\in Z^{+}$ and let  $a_n=1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+...+\dfrac{1}{n}$. Prove that$$\frac{1}{a_1^2}+\frac{1}{2a_2^2}+\frac{1}{3a_3^2}+...+\frac{1}{na_n^2}<2.$$

It is easy $a_1=1$ so we'll prove $$\frac{1}{2a_2^2}+\frac{1}{3a_3^2}+...+\frac{1}{na_n^2}<1.$$
My strategy is verifying $na_n^2$.

Indeed, $$na_n^2\le (na_n)^2=n+\dfrac{n}{2}+\dfrac{n}{3}+...+1.$$

Unfortunately, I don't see a relation between it and original inequality.

Hope you help me solve this inequality. Thank you.

Comment: On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1589914p9850138 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba_1%5E2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2a_2%5E2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3a_3%5E2%7D%2B...%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bna_n%5E2%7D%3C2%24)

Comment: @MartinR Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is a community answer, providing a solution that is almost identical to the linked on in the comment above by @Martin R. Feel free to improve this answer!*

Write $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$, which is the standard notation for the harmonic number.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k H_k^2}
&= 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k H_k^2} \\
&= 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{H_k - H_{k-1}}{H_k^2} \\
&< 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{H_k - H_{k-1}}{H_k H_{k-1}} \\
&< 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{n} \left( \frac{1}{H_{k-1}} - \frac{1}{H_k} \right) \\
&= 2 - \frac{1}{H_n} < 2.
\end{align*}